# Parsing large text file in C++

Tags: c++, text-parsing, data-processing

I have a text file of ~250k lines. Each line contains data separated by multiple spaces and possibly other symbols. I want to parse the data line by line, retrieving from each line certain components.

I have written a program that opens the input file and output file, parses line by line the input file, breaks up the line into appropriate tokens and recontructs a new line in desired format and outputs right away into the output file.

The problem is, when I run it, it stalls after parsing 70 to 92k lines. By stalls I mean the program still runs, however it doesn't process anything and the cursor in my terminal just stays there and blinks on. By using silly debugging (using cout) I checked that around line 92521 it does take an input line (a correct line), however it doesnt get through the part of breaking up into tokens and reconstructing a well-formatted line and just stops.

Below I attach the associated code. I look forward to somebody telling me what is happening i.e. why my program is stalling and in what way I might solve this issue. Thanks for your attention!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    std::string inDir("/home/marcin/jnp2/proj/data/oceny.txt");
    std::string outDir("/home/marcin/jnp2/proj/data/ocenyout.txt");
    outFile.open(outDir, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    inFile.open(inDir, std::ios::in);
    std::string line;
    int i = 1;
    while(std::getline(inFile, line, '\n')) {
    //for(int i = 0; i < 251819; i++) { // 197858
        //std::string line;
        //std::getline(inFile, line, '\n');
        //std::cout << "OK1" << std::endl;
        if(i == 92520) {
            int x;
            std::cin >> x;
        }
        if(!line.empty() && line[0] != '-' && line[0] != 'K' && line[0] != 'S') {
            //std::cout << line << std::endl;
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::string code, name, dyd_cycle, term, grade, person, tmp;
            iss >> code;
            std::size_t found;
            do {
                if(iss >> tmp) {
                    //iss >> tmp;
                    found = tmp.find("20");
                    if (found == std::string::npos)
                    if(name.empty())
                        name = tmp;
                    else
                        name = name + " " + tmp;
                    else
                        dyd_cycle = tmp;
                } else
                    return 42;
            } while (found == std::string::npos);
            //std::cout << "OK2" << std::endl;
            iss >> term;
            iss >> grade >> person;
            std::string formattedLine = code + ";" + name + ";" + dyd_cycle + ";" + term + ";" + grade + ";" + person;
            outFile << formattedLine << std::endl;
        }
        //std::cout << "OK3" << std::endl;
        std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The last output stops at
"1000-621MRB;Metody realizacji baz danych;2004/TL;3;2;LONG_CODE_THAT_IM_NOT_SUPPOSED_TO_SHOW".

I'll mention additionally that when I did it bit by bit i.e. first 50k lines, then told the program (by hard coding it to skip the first 50k lines) to start from the 50k+1 line etc there was no problem - I got the exact output I was supposed to. On the other hand, when I told it to close the files every 50k lines, re-open them and loop to the correct line for the input file, then I still got the same problem.

Edit2: I compiled it into debug and used gdb - around the critical line numbers it got the line correctly (hurray), but got stuck on iss >> code. I was using the debugger in CLion, so it just timed out after a while.

Comment: and did you try using a real debugger to break in and see whats going on?

Comment: that inner loop looks very suspicious. what if there are no "20" occurrences. Also I dont like that `if` with no braces at all.

Comment: post the contents of the last line it processes.  Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: @MaxLybbert  maybe if he has a computer with VERY little ram.   250k*80B = 20MB ram.

Comment: Your `do .. while` loop might run endless. Either way you may want to change that into a `while (iss >> tmp) {`

Comment: Inner loop condition looks strange for me. Why is it continued when nothing is found? What's the strange first `if` in inner loop?

Comment: You may want to use regular expressions.

Comment: If you copy the file and move the first 90000 lines to the end, does the problem still occur at the same text or at about the same line offset?

Comment: @MaxLybbert and he is handling the file line by line

Comment: @pm100: I'm using CLion and I used the debugger there (gdb) and it got very laggy around the critical line numbers and the command timed out simply after waiting long enough - it had taken the line correctly, but got stuck in getting the code from the input string stream (iss). Also, there is always a "20" in the occurence (that I am sure of, as the data base only contains data starting after the year 2000).

Comment: I bet you have line with unexpected format which causes `iss >> tmp;` to create infinite loop. Check whether it succeeds or not: `if (iss >> tmp) {...}`.

Comment: This won't help your actual problem, but this is a perfect example of where using `\n` would be much better than `endl`. You're forcing a buffer flush on every line, instead of letting the buffer do what buffers do best.

Comment: @gudok: I added the if(iss >> tmp) but it never enters the else to return 42.

Comment: You're right, @p100, I'll delete my comment, and try to read more closely next time.

Comment: I re-debugged it and found that there was indeed a faulty date - thank you pm100 for suggesting to look at the "20", gudok to check with an if(iss >> tmp). @kchinger: I wanted to avoid using regex, but it seems to be safer. I'll take all your suggestions into account to improve my code. Thank you very much, I'd like to include all of you in the post, but I cant include more than two ppl (including myself, if I understand correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Using cout isn't always the best way to debug, as I find that it will sometimes bog-down the terminal/overall speed of the program. You can try to use asserts or an actual debugger (such as GDB) to debug your program. A debugger will step you through your code and show you exactly what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried debugging it again and found that there is a faulty input that caused my code to go into an eternal loop.

Comment: Happy to know you figured it out. Make sure to up-vote the answer if you haven't already :)

Comment: The problem is that I gathered the answer from the comments of many people (plus yours)... I can't upvote too, as I don't have 15 rep yet :/ I'd like to give rep to 5 people for the answer and thank two others for suggestions on improving my code.

Comment: No problem! I'm trying to get more rep so that I can post questions again. Make sure you always post meaningful questions/answers ;)

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I indeed had a faulty date - the check for the "20" caused the program to go into an eternal loop. I would like to thank pm100 and George Sovetov for pointing out that bit of code as potentially dangerous. I used the debugger to find the problem - I thank Developer and pm100 for suggesting doing that. Thanks to gudok I used a check to see if iss >> tmp works, which helped me notice that my loop would become overwise eternal.

I will fix the code and use regular expressions to hopefully avoid any other forms of such errors (as per knivil's suggestion). I'll also use '\n' instead of the std::endl, the way kchinger proposed. Thank's guys for all the comments! :)